# How can I force a desktop application to use a local/side-by-side DLL?

Tags: windows-10, dll, libraries

I have a custom software installed, that ships with a certain version of the `sqlserverspatial110.dll`. It is located in the same directory as the executable itself. The software runs fine in this setup.

After installing the Veeam Backup agent on that machine (which installs an SQL server), I have another `sqlserverspatial110.dll` in the Veeam Backup installation directory and in `C:\Windows\System32\`. Since then, the custom software from above has been refusing to start, because it did not find a symbol in the said DLL.

I assume that the custom software is not loading its local DLL, because a DLL with the same name (but incompatible version) is already loaded for Veeam Backup.

I thought, I could force the custom software to use its local DLL through [Dynamic-Link Library Redirection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-redirection), but it did not work.

How can I force the software to use its own side-by-side DLL, while Veeam Backup can use the other version of the DLL (side-by-side or from `C:\Windows\System32\`)?

*Note*: I have no access to the source of the custom software and cannot recompile it. So, I am not looking for solutions, that include modifying the source code or changing build parameters. Instead, I am looking for a solution as a user of the software.

Comment: You would be correct.  Windows has a order of operations for which folders it will look at for a require system file.  The first location is indeed C:\\Windows\\System32\\. A solution that might work is to make sure the file `Veeam Backup` requires is in it's own installation folder instead of C:\\Windows\\System32\\.  This is one of the reason developers should avoid using the option to copy the file to local directory.  I have some other thoughts but would be need the exact error you received.

Comment: According to MS for win32 desktop applications the directory where the EXE files is located in should always be searched first: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications

Comment: I agree with @Robert, I would guess that the problem is different than what you think it is.  Have you tried renaming the version in the system32 directory? Have you tried looking at the libraries with something like depends or CFF Explorer?  You will need to take ownership of the file in the system32 directory to do this (of course).

Comment: Oh.. also, you can use the system internals process monitor to see EXACTLY what it is trying to load.  Getting the filters right is a PITA but once you get the hang of it, there is no better sleuthing tool.